# Select all elements except the first

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to know how to use only JavaScript to select all elements except the first one.

**My current approach:**

```js
const ps = document.querySelectorAll('div > p')

const [first, ...rest] = ps

rest.forEach(p => {
  p.innerHTML = ""
})
```

```html
<div>
  <p><span>+</span>1</p>
  <p><span>+</span>2</p>
  <p><span>+</span>3</p>
</div>
```

This works, but it returns an array instead of a NodeList. I would like it to return a NodeList.

Comment: `div > p:not(:first-child)`

Comment: For older browsers `ps.slice(1)`

Comment: @MaikLowrey Why do you want a NodeList? What can you do with a NodeList that you can't do with an array?

Comment: @Barmar I collect selections with some options inside and i though it is better to modified in a nodeList as in an array.

Comment: your solution is as good as the suggestions, especially if you'll need `first` at some point. You could of course do it in one line. `const [firstP, ...ps] = document.querySelectorAll('div > p');`

Comment: Putting the elements in an array has no effect on the elements themselves. There's really no benefit to having an array of nodes versus a NodeList of nodes.

Comment: @pilchard Thank you for your effort and time. Good suggestion from you 

Comment: The only special thing that NodeLists can do is that you can have "live" NodeLists, that automatically update when the DOM changes. `document.getElementsByClassName()` returns these, but not `document.querySelectorAll()`.

Comment: @Barmar ok thanks for your opinion. I was very unsure about this point. but if you say so, I won't worry anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

##### CSS Selector: `:not(:first-child)`

```js
const ps = [ ...document.querySelectorAll('div > p:not(:first-child)') ]
console.log(ps.map(e => e.innerHTML));
```

```html
<div>
  <p><span>+</span>1</p>
  <p><span>+</span>2</p>
  <p><span>+</span>3</p>
</div>
```

---

##### Splice: `ps.splice(0, 1);`

```js
const ps = [ ...document.querySelectorAll('div > p') ]
ps.splice(0, 1);
console.log(ps.map(e => e.innerHTML));
```

```html
<div>
  <p><span>+</span>1</p>
  <p><span>+</span>2</p>
  <p><span>+</span>3</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
const ps = document.querySelectorAll("div > p:not(:first-child)");
```